# Use options value in FormProp contributor creation

Tags: angular, typescript, abp

I'm currently working on the ABP framework using the Angular version, and I want to create a new contributor for my form. So the documentation for that is [here](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Dynamic-Form-Extensions)

Well, I added the new property to the form as:

```
const testProp = new FormProp<UpdateProfileDto>({
    type: ePropType.String,
    name: 'Test',
    displayName: '::Test',
}
);
```

It is working, but I want to display a dropdown instead a single property so apparently, there is an option to do this in the docs:

> options is a callback that is called when a dropdown is needed. It
> must return an observable. (default: undefined)

Well, so I tried to add options inside de FormProp as:

```
 options: [] or {} // does not work
```

But I need to figure out what I should send to it, I try sending an array or object but it does not work.

That options come from:

```
export declare class FormProp<R = any> extends Prop<R> {
  readonly options: PropCallback<R, Observable<ABP.Option<any>[]>> | undefined;
}
```

And the ABP.Option implements:

```
interface Option<T> {
        key: Extract<keyof T, string>;
        value: T[Extract<keyof T, string>];
    }
```

This is more of a typescript question instead a framework issue. How can I send an options list to form an options property?

I also try something like this:

```
const option1: ABP.Option<any> = {
    key: 'testKey',
    value: 'testValue'
  };

  const option2: ABP.Option<any> = {
    key: 'testKey2',
    value: 'testValue2'
  };
  
  const options: Array<ABP.Option<any>> = [];
  options.push(option1);
  options.push(option2);

const timeZoneProp = new FormProp<UpdateProfileDto>({
    type: ePropType.String,
    name: 'Test',
    displayName: '::Test',
    isExtra: true,
    options: this.options
}
);
```

But this is now throwing a new error on `this.options`:

> Object is possibly 'undefined'

Image:
[image]

So I changed `this.options` to `options` as:

```
 options: options
```

But now I'm getting a new error:

> Type 'Option[]' is not assignable to type
> 'PropCallback<UpdateProfileDto, Observable<Option[]>>'.   Type
> 'Option[]' provides no match for the signature '(data:
> Omit<PropData, "data">, auxData?: any):
> Observable<Option[]>'.ts(2322)
>
> form-props.d.ts(37, 14): The expected type comes from property
> 'options' which is declared here on type '{ validators?:
> PropCallback<UpdateProfileDto, ValidatorFn[]>; asyncValidators?:
> PropCallback<UpdateProfileDto, AsyncValidatorFn[]>; ... 15 more ...;
> name: string; }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sent an answer to your question. You have deleted the question. If you delete again, personally, I will never send an answer for you.

let's check the issue. A callback that returns undefined or observe is an option signature.

```
readonly options: PropCallback<R, Observable<ABP.Option<any>[]>> | undefined;
```

it means option should be a function not a static option like
() => of([{key:"id",value:{id:"1",name:"John"}}])

[image]